# Is there a master link for single speed chain that will fit in Shimano chain tensioner?

Tags: shimano, master-link

I've got a bike with planetary hub Shimano Alfine 8-speed and [this chain tensioner](https://i.ebayimg.com/images/g/R~kAAOSwoRBZueby/s-l300.jpg). It uses single speed chain. However master link on the chain I bought (similar to [this pic](http://cdn3.bigcommerce.com/s-d9og6faj/products/279/images/4946/Chain-KMC-MASTERLINK-Z410-BLACK-BROWN__76315.1474139501.380.500.jpg?c=2)) is too wide to fit in the chain tensioner. Is there another master link that will fit? Where do I buy it?

Edit: I made a mistake when I purchased chain with 1/8 inch width, my cog and everything else are made to work with 3/32 inch chains.

Comment: It depends on the chain you have. Do you know the brand and model or are there some marks on the chain that could help identifying it?

Comment: My guess is that you have a 1/8" chain and you would have fewer issues with your chain tensioner with a 3/32" chain which it is likely designed for. The 3/32 chain is thinner and also available for single speed configuration. Though, that would mean you would need to have 3/32" compatible rear cog and front chainring.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you have a new KMC chain (pic of the connector is KMC).

KMC definitely makes 1/8" chain connectors of the 'Missing Link' style without the extra side plate clip that is presumably causing problems.

See here: http://kmcchain.us/connectortype/single-speed-ml/

and here: http://www.kmcchain.eu/connector-bmx_track_fixie

Can't tell you if those are readily available in Russia or where the best place to buy them is.